# Is there a simple feature that builds a sublist based on value conditioning in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, list

In Matlab, when you want to get a subset of values within a vector given some value conditioning, you do the following :

```
negative_values = vec(vec<0)
positive_values = vec(vec>0)
```

I am currently using a home made function to do that in Python, but this is a bit heavy. Is there a more elegant way to proceed or a standard feature I am not aware of ? I want to be able to **concisely** do something like

```
negative_values = val.index(val<0)
positive_values = val.index(val>0)
```

but obviously this won't work with `list.index()` since it is not supposed to get an expression as argument.

Comment: Lambda expressions. `positive_values=filter(lambda x:x>0, vec)`. The only cleaner this gets is with numpy or changing languages. It's one of the things I wish vanilla Python had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as a filter like this

```
numbers = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

negatives = [number for number in numbers if number < 0]
print negatives
# [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]

positives = [number for number in numbers if number >= 0]
print positives
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function, like this

```
negatives = filter(lambda number: number <  0, numbers)
positives = filter(lambda number: number >= 0, numbers)
```

Comment: This answer is nice because it only makes use of standard functions. However I think using `numpy` -- mentioned in other answers -- can be more convenient if I don't have any space or time constraint. Which happens to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use that syntax with `numpy`:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(10)
--> a = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

a[a > 5]
--> array([6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `numpy`, which is designed as an alternative of matlab:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(-5, 5)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])

In [4]: a[a>0]
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [5]: np.where(a>0)  #used to find the indices where the condition matches
Out[5]: (array([6, 7, 8, 9]),)

In [6]: np.where(a%2==0)
Out[6]: (array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]),)
```